# The node.js with ejs web application shows me referenceerror consistently

Tags: node.js, sails.js, ejs, defined, referenceerror

I'm building a test webpage using node.js with ejs(both are the latest versions).
BTW whenever I run the server, it shows me below error messages.

```
ReferenceError: /Users/xxxxxxxx/Project/workspace/nodesails/views/user/signup.ejs:28
   26| 
   27|         <ul>
>> 28|             <% _.each(users, function(user) { %>
   29|             <li><%= user.name %> : <%= user.content %></li>
   30|             <% }) %>
   31|         </ul>

users is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/xxxxxxxx/Project/workspace/nodesails/node_modules/sails/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:236:14), <anonymous>:29:3642)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/xxxxxxxx/Project/workspace/nodesails/node_modules/sails/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:236:14), <anonymous>:29:4048)
    at /Users/xxxxxxxx/Project/workspace/nodesails/node_modules/sails/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:249:15
    at Object.exports.render (/Users/xxxxxxxx/Project/workspace/nodesails/node_modules/sails/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:287:13)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (/Users/xxxxxxxx/Project/workspace/nodesails/node_modules/sails/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:317:20)
    at View.module.exports [as engine] (/Users/xxxxxxxx/Project/workspace/nodesails/node_modules/sails/node_modules/ejs-locals/index.js:85:7)
    at View.render (/Users/xxxxxxxx/Project/workspace/nodesails/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:76:8)
    at Function.app.render (/Users/xxxxxxxx/Project/workspace/nodesails/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:506:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/Users/xxxxxxxx/Project/workspace/nodesails/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:756:7)
    at renderView (/Users/xxxxxxxx/Project/workspace/nodesails/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/views/index.js:298:20)
    at /Users/xxxxxxxx/Project/workspace/nodesails/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/views/index.js:280:20
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

the controller(UserController.js) is as below

```
var data = [
    {name: "Test 1", content:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},
    {name: "Test 2", content:"zzzzzzzzzzzzzz"},
    {name: "Test 3", content:"yyyyyyyyyyyyyy"}
];

module.exports = {

    add: function(req, res) {
        res.send('Add a user');
    },

    remove: function(req, res) {
        res.send('Remove a user');
    },

    signup: function(req, res) {
        res.send('Signup here');

        return res.view({users: data});
    }
};
```

and this is the part of the routes.js

```
'/user/signup': {
    view: 'user/signup'
},
```

and finally, the view file(view/user/signup.ejs) is

```
<div class="container clearfix">
    <div class="main">
        <h1 id="main-title">Register Here!</h1>

        <ul>
            <% _.each(users, function(user) { %>
            <li><%= user.name %> : <%= user.content %></li>
            <% }) %>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think I've tried everything I can.
Give me a helping hand, please. THANKS!

Comment: Is underscore available on the server side when the view is rendered? I would try removing "_.each" and use something like users[0].name as a test and make sure the problem is the "users" collection (which I doubt it is)

Comment: @HectorCorrea Thanks, but I tried that already and didn't work...

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work? Did you get an error accessing users[0].name?

Comment: Yes, the view didn't know what 'users' is and shoed me an same error.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, your `signup` route is wrong. You have to call `res.render` instead of `res.view` and skip the `res.send` call. At the moment you are only returning a string, and of course this does not work ...

It should be something such as

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  signup: function(req, res) {
    res.render('signup', { users: data });
  }
};
```

where `signup` is your view (`signup.ejs`, but you do not have to provide the extension, as Express automatically knows which extension to use based on the view engine configured).

Comment: Unfortunately it returns a same error, in fact I tried this already.

Comment: This is the sample code in the Sails document and I followed this but it doesn't work. Are there some bugs in this versions(0.8.4)? [link](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/views)